Uniform convergence of $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^3+x^2}$
Let's consider $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^3+x^2}$$
First, I check the convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^3+x^2}$ to find the domain $D$ of $f$. I have that:
$$\left|\frac{x^n}{n^3+x^2}\right|=\frac{|x|^n}{n^3+x^2}\overset{n}{\longrightarrow} 0 \iff |x|\leq 1$$
So, $f$ is well defined on $D=[-1,1]$.
Because of the sequence $\displaystyle\frac{x^n}{n^3+x^2}\longrightarrow 0$ if $|x|\leq 1$, I obtain that:
$$\sup_{x\in [-1,1]}\left|\frac{x^n}{n^3+x^2}\right|\leq \sup_{x\in [-1,1]}\left|\frac{x^n}{n^3}\right|=\frac{1}{n^3}\longrightarrow 0$$
Therefore, $f$ is uniformly convergent in $D$.
Is it correct? I'm not sure about the discussion for the uniform convergence, can someone help me to justify it better?

If you  point out that you use "Weierstrass M-test" to show $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^3+x^2}$ uniformly convergent in $[-1,1]$, that will be better!
